# Labels in ggplot after applying weights

Tags: r, ggplot2, label, weighted

I draw a bar plot with the weights included, but when I want to add labels to the columns, a histogram without the weights is taken into account. Do I have to use the after_stat argument? Not sure how to use it properly? Thanks for the help!

```
g <- ggplot(Y, aes(x=Q6, fill=Q3))
g + geom_bar()
g + geom_bar(aes(weight = XU$Q2), position="dodge", na.rm=TRUE)
g + geom_text(stat = "count", aes(label = after_stat(count)), vjust = -1)


structure(list(data = structure(list(Q6 = c("red", "red", "blue", 
"green", "green", "green", "red", "red", "red", "grey", "purple", 
"white", "black", "black", "black", "black", "black"), Q3 = c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L
), Q2 = c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -17L
)), layers = list(), scales = <environment>, mapping = structure(list(
x = ~Q6, fill = ~Q3), class = "uneval"), theme = list(), 
coordinates = <environment>, facet = <environment>, plot_env = 
<environment>, 
labels = list(x = "Q6", fill = "Q3")), class = c("gg", "ggplot"
))
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you could include either the data you are trying to plot, or a sample of it, in the question. You can use the `dput` command for this purpose :)

Comment: Hey, I updated the question with the sample data.

Answer (score 0):

I am not exactly sure about what you are trying to show, but maybe you can use this kind of strategy. First i transform the dataset to have one row per `Q6` taking the sum of the individual rows per group. Then i can use `geom_col` and `geom_text` like this

```
library(tidyverse)
data = structure(list(Q6 = c("red", "red", "blue", 
                             "green", "green", "green", "red", "red", "red", "grey", "purple", 
                             "white", "black", "black", "black", "black", "black"), Q3 = c(1L, 
                                                                                           1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L
                             ), Q2 = c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                       1L, 1L, 1L, 1L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -17L
                                       ))

data %>%
  group_by(Q6) %>%
  summarise(Q3 = sum(Q3), Q2 = sum(Q2)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=Q6, y=Q2, fill=Q3)) +
    geom_col() +
    geom_text(aes(label = Q2, group = Q6), vjust = -.2)
```

[image]